# Can vector of vectors get reallocated because one of elements got reallocated?

Tags: c++, stdvector

Lets say I have a vector of vectors:

```
vector< vector<int> > table;
```

I know that vector can get reallocated if it doesn't have sufficient capacity.
I am wondering if there is a possibility of vector *table* reallocating if I do this:

```
table[i].resize(1000);
```

Is it possible that reallocation of *table[i]* also reallocates *table*?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it won't have any incidence: the implementation of vectors is based on an array in most case (it's pretty much the idea of vectors), though this is not set in stone in the language specification. At any rate, the dynamic nature of vectors precludes any form of sequence inlined in the data structure, ie. the sequence of elements managed by the `vector` class cannot be inside the `vector` class, but is necessarily a chunck of memory located elsewhere, with a pointer in the class.

Your datatype is therefore similar to a dynamic array of pointers to dynamic arrays. Reallocating one pointed array will not have an effect on the pointer array.

Answer (score 6):

No. This will not cause a reallocation in `table`.

The only operator/function called on `table` is the `[]` operator, which promises constant time. If re-allocation happened, this would violate the constant time promise.

The reason why you can change the vector size of the sub-vectors (the `table[i]`s) without requiring additional space to be allocated in the top-level vector is a vector's storage is managed via a pointer to a block of memory. Thus, increasing the amount of elements that a vector uses doesn't actually change the size of the vector *object*.

`table[i].size()` changes without changing `sizeof(table[i])`.

Answer (score 1):

No, because the content of `table` is unchanged - it still contains exactly the same instances as before. Only the storage of `table[i]` needed to be reallocated. `vector` contains a pointer to the storage - the size of vector object is always the same, only the referenced array can grow or shrink. Therefore, table[i] is not growing, if that's what you ask - only the array it points to is.

Answer (score 1):

No. Calling a method of a `vector`'s element wouldn't affect the `vector` itself.

Consider this as the following call: parent_object.child_object.Method(), where child_object knows nothing about the parent_object. The Method() cannot change state of parent_object.

The same goes for the vector of vectors. (Technically, here you are storing an array of pointers to arrays. Resizing one of the child arrays is a local operation and changes the appropriate pointer, but doesn't change the size of parent array.)

Answer (score 1):

No, that can't happen. `resize` doesn't change the size of the vector *object* – it only changes the dynamic storage that the vector *manages*. So from the point of view of the outer vector, all the elements remain unchanged (and have the same, small size).